# How can i handle the 'pull to refresh ' in webdriver(or selenium)

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, webdriver, web-crawler

i want to know how can i handle the 'pull to refresh' in webdriver(or selenium)

i'm making a simple program that is facebook crawler using webdrvier and beautifulsoup. When i request friends list of timeline list, all of data exists before pull to refresh. i wanna refresh automated logic.

please answer me

Comment: Do you know what the 'pull to refresh' is? when your scrollbar is down, some new information appear. i want to make automated implementation through webdriver. but i don't know how it is;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ActionChains` to simulate scroll down

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("id")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

That will scroll the screen so that the element will be visible.